# Python - Service, how to get a code review

Tags: python, code-reviews

I am usually a PHP and Delphi developer and have been getting into Python lately.

I am developing an app and would love to get some feedback on the code, there are few things which I would love to tidy up myself but I am sure there are other things.

Where / how is a good way to get in touch with an experienced Python dev? Paying is no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the best Pythonistas can be found here:

http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-list

Also you can try these guys:

https://stackoverflow.com/badges/51/python

Answer (score 8):

You could also try [Code Review - Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq)

> for **sharing code from projects you are working on** for peer review. If you are looking for feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project in the following areas…
>
> - Best practices and design pattern usage
> - Security issues
> - Performance
> - Correctness in unanticipated cases
>
> then you are in the right place..

Answer (score 1):

I would check to see if there is a local Python Users Group.  People on those lists are usually interested in helping out other Python developers.